# Building and running most basic Verilator

Tags: verilator

Trying to get started with basic [Verilator c++ example](https://verilator.org/guide/latest/example_cc.html#example-c-execution) on Windows 10.

#### Attempt 1: Using WSL, install from apt

- `apt install verilator` seems to run fine
- `verilator --version` returns
  `Verilator 4.038 2020-07-11 rev v4.036-114-g0cd4a57ad`
- `export VERILATOR_ROOT=/usr/share/verilator` (after a few attempts at this step)
- Using `our.v` and `sim_main.cpp` as in the example
- `verilator --cc --exe --build -j 0 -Wall sim_main.cpp our.v` returns `%Error: -j accepts positive integer, but 0 is passed`.  Ok so maybe that's a version 5 argument.
- Try again `verilator --cc --exe --build -j 1 -Wall sim_main.cpp our.v` returns

  ```
    Can't exec "/usr/share/verilator/verilator_bin": No such file or directory at /usr/bin/verilator line 173.
    %Error: verilator: Misinstalled, or VERILATOR_ROOT might need to be in environment
    %Error: Verilator threw signal -1. Suggest trying --debug --gdbbt
    %Error: Command Failed /usr/share/verilator/verilator_bin --cc --exe --build -j 1 -Wall sim_main.cpp our.v
  ```
- `verilator_bin` is installed next to `verilator` in `/usr/bin`, not in `/usr/share/verilator` which is where `VERILATOR_ROOT` points to.
- When I had `VERILATOR_ROOT` accidentally pointing to `/usr/bin` in third step above, the tool could not find `verilated.mk`
- I went into `obj_dir/` and did `make Vour` directly, but it complained about not finding `verilated_heavy.h`
- So it looks like `VERILATOR_ROOT` is the main lever here, and pointing to either `/usr/bin` or `/usr/share/verilator` doesn't work, but in different ways.

#### Attempt 2: Using WSL, build V5.008 from git source, from [instructions](https://verilator.org/guide/latest/install.html#installation)

- `apt remove verilator` to remove attempt 1
- Download from git and build everything as per "Git Quick Install" section
- Needed to install `help2man` before `make install`, which is not in instructions
- `verilator --version` returns `Verilator 5.008 2023-03-04 rev v5.008-32-gaaaf8e75a`
- `make test` -- all passed
- `which verilator` returns `/usr/local/bin/verilator`
- `export VERILATOR_ROOT=/usr/local/bin` then `verilator --cc --exe --build -j 0 -Wall sim_main.cpp our.v` returns ``` Cannot find verilated_std.sv``/usr/local/share/verilator/include/verilated_std.sv ```.
- Put `export VERILATOR_ROOT=/usr/local/share/verilator` in `.bashrc`, then restart, then `verilator --cc --exe --build -j 0 -Wall sim_main.cpp our.v` returns

  ```
    Can't exec "/usr/local/share/verilator/verilator_bin": No such file or directory at /usr/local/bin/verilator line 207.
    %Error: verilator: Misinstalled, or VERILATOR_ROOT might need to be in environment
    %Error: Verilator threw signal -1. Suggest trying --debug --gdbbt
    %Error: Command Failed /usr/local/share/verilator/verilator_bin --cc --exe --build -j 1 -Wall sim_main.cpp our.v
  ```
- So basically same problem as attempt #1 -- I can't find a good setting for `VERILATOR_ROOT`
- Checked https://github.com/verilator/verilator/issues/1116
- Removed `VERILATOR_ROOT` from .bashrc, start WSL again
- `make clean`, `autoconf`, `make`, `make test`, `make install` all good
- Same results as above after updating `VERILATOR_ROOT` to `/usr/local/share/verilator` and optionally adding `$VERILATOR_ROOT/bin` to path.

#### Attempt 3: Using MSVC and CMAKE, build V5.008 from git source

- More difficulties, but eventually got a binary
- Program does not generate any output.

Answer (score 1):

I just needed to unset VERILATOR_ROOT completely, even after make install.